# woocommerce product tags display

Tags: tags, cloud

I am using shopfront for sons website, while I can usually manage to sort out things with a little research (thanks everyone) I am stuck,  He has a lot of tags showing on every item he sells (which are archery targets) and we want to retain the tags but not display them actually on the product page (I hope that is clear)

Anyone any ideas on how to do this easily ? or at all ?
  Thanks to everyone in advance

Thanks for the answer but as much as I have searched "Storefront Theme" I can't find the place to edit the meta tag cloud display as shown on your link,    however I think I have found the display for Meta Tags, but I am not sure what to change,  could someone have a look and let me know if it is just a simple edit needed ?

product_meta{font-size:.875em;padding-top:1em;border-top:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.05)}.single-product div.product .product_meta .posted_in,.single-product div.product .product_meta .sku_wrapper,.single-product div.product .product_meta .tagged_as{display:block}.single-product div.product .product_meta .posted_in:last-child,.single-product div.product .product_meta .sku_wrapper:last-child,.single-product div.product .product_meta .tagged_as:last-child{border-bottom:0}.single-product div.product .product_meta a{font-weight:600;text-decoration:underline}.single-product div.product .product_meta a:hover{text-decoration:none}.stock:empty::before{display:none}.stock.in-stock{color:#0f834d}.stock.out-of-

Comment: I forgot to add the page / site details https://3dtargets.co.uk/product/flying-golden-eagle-3d-field-archery-target/      thanks

Comment: You can edit the page link into the question rather than leaving it as a comment.

Comment: I guess the simplest fix is to just delete the tags line from the meta template: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.5.5/templates/single-product/meta.php#L37 It looks like you can do this by copying the template into your theme (see instructions at the top) and editing it there, rather than modifying woocommerce itself, which would get lost in an update. Or you can style `span.tagged_as` to be hidden in your CSS and leave the template as-is. However both of these may have SEO implications, and I don't know anything about that. Hopefully someone else will know the best way!

Comment: The code you've posted is the CSS generated from the theme's SASS. I'm not sure you can just modify that, no. It turns out you [can't just 'display:none' a span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884549/span-elements-still-visible-after-displaynone) as I suggested. If you want to edit the single product meta template that I linked to then you'll have to copy it into your theme, as in the instructions at the top of the file.